# Winforms and SQL application within LAN

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms, connection-string

I have a question regarding some Winforms app that will run on LAN. The application is connected to the SQL database which will be stored in one of the servers in LAN. As connection string I used :

```
Data Source=MICROSERVER\JAHSHSQL;Initial Catalog=test_database;Integrated Security=False;Network Library=dbmssocn;Connect Timeout=15;User Instance=False;User ID=user;Password=password;
```

For any of the server requests, I create a new connection and drop it as soon as the data is taken or updated. In server Connections tab, under "Maximum number of concurrent connections (0=unlimited)", 0 is set. 
Is this OK for some Windows application that might be run from several computers at the same time? Do I need to set something more to have a valid and resistant connection between server and application? 
Regards,

Comment: The short answer is yes, close the connection as soon as you are done (because of connection pooling). For the long answer read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling

Comment: Thank You Kevin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, better use windows security instead of SQL Server username + password. Then you don't have to store the password as a part of your connection string, and it's much more secure. Other then that, your description seems good. As long as you are disposing your instances of `SqlConnection` ASAP so that [it's underlying connection can return to the pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling) you should not run into problems with such configuration.